# API Mapping Templates with Serverless

Tags: aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

When using `http`-event with serverless-framework multiple response status are created [by default](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#status-codes).
In case of error a Lambda returns an error message stringified in the `errorMessage` property, so you need a mapping template such as

`$input.path('$.errorMessage')`

for any status code you want to use. F.e.:

```js
"response": {
    "statusCodes": {
      "200": {
        "pattern": ""
      },
      "500": {
        "pattern": ".*\"success\":false.*",
        "template": "$input.path('$.errorMessage')"
      }
    }
  }
```

But the serverless-framework does not create one by default, thus rendering the default status codes useless. If I would create a mapping template myself, the default response status would be overwritten by my custom ones.

What is the correct way of mapping with the default status codes created by the serverless-framework@1.27.3?